# How many ways are there to give 21 different books to 3 people, A, B, C, so that A's + B's = 2C's books?

Tags: permutations, combinations

Only thing I found is that A and B will take 14 books, while C has to get 7. Any thoughts?
Thanks in advance.

Edit:
So the question is not answered, we are looking for ways to give the books to the three people with the above conditions, though I might have come up with a solution, which I'd be glad to discuss about.

Solution (?):
First of all, we give 7 books to C, but how many ways are there? C(n,r) = C(21, 7). Then the remaining 14 books have to be given to A and B, but B is actually not having any impact, you can give A the 14 with $2^n$ -1 ways, n = 14. B will either way take the remaining books A didn't take.
Multiplying those 2 numbers we take the required ways.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Then break down each possibility of $A+B=14.$ That lists each way to do it.

Comment: If you look at the title I think you will see why I supposed C = 7, A + B = 14.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If A gets k (up to and including 14) books out of a selection of 21, then B must get the rest of the 14 books (14-k) from the rest of the selection (21-k). Determining the books for A and B also determines the books for C.

$\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{14}\binom{21}{k}\binom{21-k}{14-k} = 1,905,131,520$

Answer (score -1):

Hint:

Obviously you can take a book from A and give it to B (or the other way round) while still satisfying the conditions.

Write the two conditions as $$A+B+C=21$$ $$A+B=2C$$
You have two equations and three unknowns, so there is not a single unique solution, but in this example you can find $C$ and $A+B$ and it is not difficult to do so.  You are already most of the way there.

Comment: I really do not understand how there is any other way other than A + B = 14, C = 7, maybe I'm stuck. Thanks for the response!

Comment: @kikiking That is the solution.  If you want, you can also say $0 \le A \le 14$ and $B=14-A$, but there is nothing more to it than that.  So now you know how many solutions there are. $A$ can be any of $0,1,2,3,4,\ldots,14$ and if you know $A$ then you know $B$ and $C$.